# Not able to connect android app to server using web services?

Tags: android

I am trying to connect my android application to existing web services which is live on cPanel. I am using retrofit library to connect it to server. As I am connecting it is giving me nullPointerException even after providing everything. How can I solve this issue?

Api.java

```
   package com.example.blastzebrarfid.API;

   import android.os.Build;

   import com.example.blastzebrarfid.Interfaces.ApiInterface;
   import com.google.gson.Gson;
   import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.List;

   import okhttp3.ConnectionSpec;
   import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
   import retrofit2.Retrofit;
   import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

   public class Api {
   private static final String BASE_URL = 
   "https://beaconblast.net/services/";

   private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
    List tlsSpecs = Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS);

    /* providing backwards-compatibility for API lower than Lollipop: */
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
        tlsSpecs = Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
    }

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionSpecs(tlsSpecs)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    return retrofit;

}

    public static ApiInterface client = 
    getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
 }
```

ApiInterface.java
package com.example.blastzebrarfid.Interfaces;

```
    import com.example.blastzebrarfid.model.ItemListPOJO;
    import com.example.blastzebrarfid.model.ItemListRequestPOJO;
    import com.example.blastzebrarfid.model.ReturnListResponsePOJO;

    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.http.Body;
    import retrofit2.http.Field;
    import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
    import retrofit2.http.GET;
    import retrofit2.http.POST;
    import retrofit2.http.Query;

    public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("verification/org-id-check.php")
    Call<Void> checkOrgId(@Field("orgId") String orgId);

    @POST("item/alien-item-list.php")
   Call<ItemListPOJO> fetchItemList(@Body ItemListRequestPOJO 
  itemListRequestPOJO);

  }
```

AppPreferences.java

```
    package com.example.blastzebrarfid.data;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;

    public class AppPreferences {

    private static SharedPreferences prefs;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static final String PREFS = "blastZebraPrefs";
    private static final String ORG_ID = "orgId";

    public static void initializePreferences(Context context) {
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void setOrgId(String orgId) {
    editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(ORG_ID, orgId);
    editor.apply();
   }

   public static String getOrgId() {
    return prefs.getString(ORG_ID, null);
   }
  }
```

LaunchActivity.Java

```
    package com.example.blastzebrarfid;

    public class LaunchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppCompatButton btnDone;
    private AppCompatEditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

    installGooglePlayServicesProvider(getApplicationContext());
    init();
    }

    private void init() {
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Org ID 
    Selection");
    editText = findViewById(R.id.actLaunch_editText);
    btnDone = findViewById(R.id.actLaunch_btn);
    btnDone.setEnabled(false);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, 
    int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int 
    i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                btnDone.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                btnDone.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
     });

     editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new 
     TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent 
     keyEvent) {
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || i == 13) {
                if (textView.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    checkOrgId();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "Please provide 
      a value in all " +
                            "fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkOrgId();
        }
    });

   }


    private void checkOrgId() {
       final String orgId = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    btnDone.setEnabled(false);
    Api.client.checkOrgId(orgId).enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) 
    {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                AppPreferences.setOrgId(orgId);
                Log.e("Org ID: ", AppPreferences.getOrgId());
                goToNextActivity();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "Invalid Org ID", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            btnDone.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("ambb", "onFailure:  " + t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btnDone.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}

private static void installGooglePlayServicesProvider(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { //Devices with Android 5.1+ should support TLS 1.x out of the box
        try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(context);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            Log.e("ProviderInstaller", "Google Play Services is out of date!", e);
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(context, e.getConnectionStatusCode());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            Log.e("ProviderInstaller", "Google Play Services is unavailable!", e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    goToNextActivity();
}

private void goToNextActivity() {
    if (AppPreferences.getOrgId() != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchBooks.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

}
```

Android Error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.blastzebrarfid, PID: 24484
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.blastzebrarfid/com.example.blastzebrarfid.LaunchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4206)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4238)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.blastzebrarfid.data.AppPreferences.getOrgId(AppPreferences.java:24)
    at com.example.blastzebrarfid.LaunchActivity.goToNextActivity(LaunchActivity.java:146)
    at com.example.blastzebrarfid.LaunchActivity.onResume(LaunchActivity.java:142)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1454)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7962)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4196)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4238) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] to show what you are doing. Then explain what happens. Show any errors or other output. And describe what you want instead.

Comment: You need to post the appropriate code and tell us what line the NPE occurred on  for us to help.

Comment: 'code uploaded. Api call giving me null pointer exception error.'